# Can cows accurately predict when it is going to rain?

Tags: zoology, weather, divination

And do they show when they know it's going to rain by lying down, as the common saying suggests. Or is this just folklore?

A quote on [this Discovery Channel discussion board](http://community.discovery.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/9701967776/m/4311965169) says this:

> Cows are quite large and heavy which could easily put a lot of strain
> on their joints and cause a lot of arthritis. **Arthritis flares up
> when a low pressure system comes along, which could make cows want to
> lay down and take the pain off their aching joints.** Of course there
> is no real way to test this. It is just a thought. With no way to test
> it it's just pseudo-science, but it does at least show there could be
> a logical reason this belief COULD be true.

Have there ever been any studies on the subject? Any conclusions?

Comment: As for the arthritis as a possible cause see http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2001/do-weather-changes-affect-arthritis

Comment: How long before the rain do they lay down?

Comment: Look, seriously, if they are going to lie down, it aint going to be just before it hooeys down now are they.  I would have thought this ones just plain daft.