# Does extremely low frequency radiation from mobile phones and tablets have adverse health effects?

Tags: environmental-health, electromagnetism, radiation, mobile-phones

Is ELF (extremely low frequency) radiation emitted by the electrical appliances' battery's current considered to have adverse health effects, or 
is this radiation too low to be considered?

I'd like to keep the focus specifically on mobile phones and tablets, and please take in account that those devices are put on 'airplane mode' to eliminate the RF radiation emitted by 3g and Wifi.

Therefore this question address the effects of ELF only from a mobile phone or tablet running on battery.

The existence of some scientific papers show this may be a valid concern. For example,

- [Cell phone radiation: Evidence from ELF and RF studies supporting more inclusive risk identification and assessment](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19264460) implies there may be a risk to be identified and assessed
- [Assessment of extremely low frequency magnetic field exposure from GSM mobile phones](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bem.21827/abstract) implies, at least, that there is such a thing as ELF magnetic field exposure from mobile phones

Comment: Can you link us to a notable article or quote on this?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I arbitrarily referenced a couple of papers which I hoped may support that the question is notable.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I've reverted my downvote. My quick google had only shown me a couple of very odd tinfoilhat websites...

Comment: @RoryAlsop I haven't read those papers. I'd like to assume that there's no risk at all, but, what do I know...

Comment: I have a hard time believing this isn't a duplicate. Has this question _really_ not been asked before? It's such a common scaremongering claim...

Comment: @BrianS I think it was asked yesterday quoting a page from the Mercola web site (but the quote from Mercola seemed too senseless to be answerable, so the question was closed and then maybe deleted).

Comment: Oh my. If such ELF was harmful, how could anybody survive NMR imaging? I'd estimate that if you scale the relative ELF intensity you receive in an MRT tube, compared to a mobile phone, to the phone's microwave emission, then this would correspond to an oven able to evaporate your body within seconds. Probably, even an ordinary permanent magnet would be a deadly weapon, if you throw it at somebody. — Hopefully, someone will reference a proper calculation of this.

Comment: ["ELF" (i.e. extremely low frequency)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) is not microwave (the usual subject of these claims for cell phones) but much lower frequency and longer wavelength. Not that phones are going to be very efficient transmitters in this band: they simply aren't big enough to do a good job. But this looks like a distinct version of this kind of scaremongering, more closely related to high tension power-line claims than the usual cell-phone one.

Comment: @BrianS The question seems to be asked and answered here  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/569/do-mobile-phones-have-anything-to-do-with-brain-cancer and here  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/can-radiation-from-wireless-phones-and-computers-harm-babies

Comment: @BrianS these posts are concerned with RF which are susceptible. I'm looking what happens when RF is cut off and you use the phone running on battery only,hence the ELF emitted